# Unknown frame descriptor while reading zst file on hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez, zstd

I have a file **a.csv.zst** and i ve created textfile table.

When i select on hive i see first 100 rows without an error but when i select `count(*)` it gives an error `unknown frame descriptor`

I can decompress my file on linux with `zstd -dc a.csv.zstd`

How can i read it on hive?

It works on mr but not with tez

I didnt give an option to show compression level to hive table as i know the default value is 3 and i m not sure the file zstd compression level

Comment: Is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-14099 resolved in your Hadoop version?

Comment: In hadoop 3.3.4 and hive 3.1.3 not resolved

Comment: HDFS-14099 shown as resolved in 
"Fix Version/s:
3.4.0, 3.2.3, 3.3.2" 
 If you are on 3.3.4 it means that something else is going on. Posting a full stacktrace would probably help to understand what.

Comment: it says : Error while processing statement: Failed: Execution Error , return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.teztask. Vertex failed. ....... java.lang.internalerror: unknown frame descriptor at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zstd.ZStandardDecompressor.inflateBytesDirect.........

Comment: I meant the complete stacktrace as found in a tez container log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My tez version is 0.10.2

So it has hadoop-common 3.1 jar which has zstd decompressor java class and that jar has a bug and fixed after 3.2 version

When i changed hadoop common har it works